# Form validation by country value

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a query form with a country list. Mobile number and e-mail validation are working fine when the country India is selected, but when the user selects another country, I need mobile number validation off. Here is the code for validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submitfeedback").click(function() {
            var email = $("#fdbk_email").val();
            var  enqMobileNo= $("#fdbk_num").val();
            $("#returnmessage").empty(); // To empty previous error/success message.
            // Checking for blank fields.
            if (email == '' || enqMobileNo == '')
                {
                    $("#returnmessage").append("<span>Enter your vaild E-mail & Mobile No.<span>");
                    return false;
                }
            var mailPattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
            if(!mailPattern.test(email))
                {
                    $("#returnmessage").append("<span>Enter your valid email address!<span>");
                    return false;
                }
            var phoneNumberPattern = /^[0-9]{10}$/;
            if(!phoneNumberPattern.test(enqMobileNo))
                {
                    $("#returnmessage").append("<span>Enter your 10 digits mobile no only.<span>");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct that you don't want to check mobile no when country is not India then I assumed your country is a dropdown field with id "country" then you can do following:

```
if($('#country option:selected').val() == 'india')
{
        var phoneNumberPattern = /^[0-9]{10}$/;
        if(!phoneNumberPattern.test(enqMobileNo))
        {
            $("#returnmessage").append("<span>Enter your 10 digits mobile no only.<span>");
            return false;
        }
}
```

Please update id selector and value accordingly

Comment: tell me one thing what i will mention here:  #country option:selected. cox i am not so good in Jquery.

Comment: This is my country select code:   <select name="enqCountryResidence" id="enqCountryResidence" >

Comment: I assumed your field declared as <select id="country" name="country_opt">..</select>. So here if your id is different then change accordingly. If you are not sure, paste your html here

Comment: oh. then replace country with enqCountryResidence. means it would be #enqCountryResidence option:selected

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr. Hussain. It works :) You solve my prob. i was trying this from yesterday. . Thanks once again.

Comment: Hello Hussian, :) Are you there. Need your help Once again.

Comment: code is same as previous one..... now i want to put validation that if country is India than only 10 digits will enter. If user try to enter more than 10 digits he can't.